# MongoDB NodeJS or Java Driver

Tags: mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB Java Driver. I have many requests and it is limited by this driver, requesting 1 at a time.

I want to perform async requests to MongoDB. Hence there is a need to change my program to either an MongoDB Async Java Driver OR use a MongoDB NodeJS Driver.

Which do you recommend? My app deals with a lot of JSON objects. I am fluent in both Java and Javascript :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you want to issue multiple requests from your app to mongodb simultaneously, or that your server is only allowing one client request at a time?  And do you have an existing app you'd be rewriting from Java to JS if you switch to Node?

Comment: I want to issue multiple requests from my app to mongodb. :)